# Declare array of strings

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I was trying to declare an array of strings like so:

```
str ar1[2] = ['One','Two'];
```

Getting a syntax error. How can I initialize and assign an array like above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`['One', 'Two']` is a container in the axapta. axapta has no syntax for initialize an array. use:

```
str ar1[2];

ar1[1] = 'One';
ar1[2] = 'Two';
```

Answer (score 4):

In AX, you'r trying to assign a container collection to an array collection. Which is incorrect, Therefore you can try to follow one of the approach listed below:

Using an array:

```
str number[2];

// Array starts at one in AX; hence number[0] will clear every value in the array
number[1] = 'One';
number[2] = 'Two';
```

The other way, would be to use a container:

```
container con;

con += 'One';  // Equivalent to 'con = conIns(con, conLen(con)+1, 'One');
con += 'Two';  // Equivalent to 'con = conIns(con, conLen(con)+1, 'Two');
```

or a shortcut would be to use:

```
container con = ['One', 'Two'];
```

Comment: remember that [Container are immutable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa874816.aspx):

> Some X++ statements with containers might appear like they modify a container, but inside the system this never occurs. Instead, the data from the original container is combined with data from the command to build a *new* container.